# How to add a unique custom attribute for a customer?

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, custom-attributes

I was able to add a custom attribute called 'Username' to the Magento Customer model.

The install-function in InstallData.php looks like this:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $this->logger->info("Username data installed.");

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'username', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Username',
        'input' => 'text',
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'unique' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'username')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();


}
```

Everything works correctly, but the 'unique' => true does not work. I found out that this field is not used for customers and uniqueness must be programmed manually.

So I basically want to check the uniqueness of the attribute just **before a customer is saved to the database** (so just before account creation).

I found this code in app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/ResourceModel/Customer.php in _beforeSave().

```
    $connection = $this->getConnection();
    $bind = ['email' => $customer->getEmail()];

    $select = $connection->select()->from(
        $this->getEntityTable(),
        [$this->getEntityIdField()]
    )->where(
        'email = :email'
    );
    if ($customer->getSharingConfig()->isWebsiteScope()) {
        $bind['website_id'] = (int)$customer->getWebsiteId();
        $select->where('website_id = :website_id');
    }
    if ($customer->getId()) {
        $bind['entity_id'] = (int)$customer->getId();
        $select->where('entity_id != :entity_id');
    }

    $result = $connection->fetchOne($select, $bind);
    if ($result) {
        throw new AlreadyExistsException(
            __('A customer with the same email already exists in an associated website.')
        );
    }
```

It is exactly this behaviour for the email that I want to replicate for my username.

Does anyone have an idea how I do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You need to InstallData.php like below code :

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $this->logger->info("Username data installed.");

    /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
    $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

    /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
    $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
    $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

    $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'username', [
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'label' => 'Username',
        'input' => 'text',
        'backend' => \Vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Backend\Username::class,
        'required' => false,
        'visible' => true,
        'user_defined' => true,
        'unique' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'sort_order' => 1000,
        'position' => 1000,
        'system' => 0,
    ]);

    $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'username')
    ->addData([
        'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
        'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
        'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'checkout_register', 'customer_account_create', 'customer_account_edit', 'adminhtml_checkout'],
    ]);

    $attribute->save();


}
```

Please create Username.php file in  \Vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Backend and code like

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Attribute\Backend;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotDeleteException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;

class Username extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\AbstractBackend
{
    /**
     * Generate and set unique Username to customer
     *
     * @param Customer $object
     * @return void
     */
    protected function checkUniqueUsername($object)
    {
        $attribute = $this->getAttribute();
        $entity = $attribute->getEntity();
        $attributeValue = $object->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
        $increment = null;
        while (!$entity->checkAttributeUniqueValue($attribute, $object)) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Account with Username is already exist'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make username unique before save
     *
     * @param Customer $object
     * @return $this
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $this->checkUniqueUsername($object);
        return parent::beforeSave($object);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$attributeValue` and `$increment` variable values never used. Is your code correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute's backend model. For a reference you can have a look at the product's attribute SKU backend model `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Backend\Sku`

Answer (score 1):

You can create an event :

```
<customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <mymodule_customer_save_before>
                        <class>mymodule/observer</class>
                        <method>checkUniqueAttribute</method>
                    </mymodule_customer_save_before>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_before>
```

And in your observer :

```
/**
     * Check customer attribute which must be unique
     *
     * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     * @@see customer_save_before
     */
    public function checkUniqueAttribute(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var Mage_Customer_Model_Customer $customer */
        $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
        foreach ($customer->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->getIsUnique()) {
                $collection = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                    ->getCollection()
                    ->addAttributeToFilter($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $customer->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()))
                    ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',   array('neq' => $customer->getId()));

                if ($collection->getSize()) {
                    Mage::throwException(sprintf(
                        'The value %s for %s is already used',
                        $customer->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode()),
                        $attribute->getStoreLabel()
                    ));
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
```

Comment: Maxime Huran, Question is related to magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not really answering your question but here is a free extension that allow you to use username instead of email. Well exactly this extension allow you tu use both field as credential. (sorry for my english...)

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/username-support-login-register-checkout-by-diglin.html

Comment: This is extension for M1, not M2